# Integrate $\int^a_0x^3 - x \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}$ to find the area

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

> (a) Solve the equation: $$\int^a_0x^3 - x \mathop{\mathrm{d}x} = 0, a > 0$$
>
> (b) For this value of $a$, find the total area enclosed between the $x$-axis  and the curve $y=x^3 - x$ for $0 \leq x \leq a$.

I can quite easily solve the first part but for part (b) when I substitute $\sqrt{2}$ I just get $0$, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is clear that the integral must be $0$, because you chose $a$ in exercise $a)$ in such a way.

Comment: Draw a picture. If they mean area below the $x$-axis plus area above the $x$-axis, we want $\int_0^1 (x-x^3)\,dx+\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}(x^3-x)\,dx$.

Comment: You find the number $1$ by determining, where $f(x)=0$. If you take the absolute values of the integrals, you need not consider whether they are positive or negative. Area and integral coincide only , if $f(x)\ge 0$ on the whole interval.

Comment: The image you posted the first time used the function $x^3-x$ in part (a) as well as part (b). If that's what you intend, please fix the post and the title.

Comment: @rogerl done; someone edited it wrongly for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to consider that $f(x)=x^3-x$ has a root at $x=1$. Therefore you have to calculate

$$-\int_0^1 (x^3 -x) \, dx+\int_1^{\sqrt{2}} (x^3 -x) \, dx$$

See the graph of $f(x)$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem part(a) is not different from part (b), as it is asking to just check your work.. so getting zero between $ 0, \sqrt 2 $ shows your result is in fact correct.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can determine the area between the curve and the $x$-axis as follows :

You determine the roots of $f(x)$. You only need the roots inside the given interval.

To get the intervals :

Go from the left end of the interval to the smallest root. From here to the next larger root , continue in this manner, and finally from the largest root to the right end of the interval.

Take the absolute values of the integrals over the intervals. Add these values and you are done.